# On enter, search for the string in db

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code:

```
<body>
    Please make your selection:
    <div id="div1">
       <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="button" value="Insert" onclick="form.html" />
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" value="View" onclick="window.location='view-master.php';" />
            </td>
            <td>        
            <input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="edit.html" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="showsearchform()" />
            </td>
      </tr>  
    </div>      
</body>
```

then the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showsearchform()
 {
   var tr = document.createElement("tr");
   var td = document.createElement("td");
   var label = document.createElement("label");
   label.id = "label1";
   label.value = "Surname";

   var input = document.createElement("input");
   tr.appendChild(td);
   td.appendChild(label);
   td.appendChild(input);

   var element = document.getElementById("div1");
   element.appendChild(tr);

   $('#input').keyup(function (e) {
     var str = $('#search').val();
     var url = "search.php";
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       location.href = url;
     }
   });
 }
</script>
```

when i click on search i get the inoutbox, but what i want to do now is when i type a surname into the box and hit enter i want to connect to the db and search for this surname

I can do the db stuff just not sure of the JS and Jquery

Comment: You need Ajax here. BTW, I would rewrite pure js to jQuery, since you use it anyway.

Comment: oops yes will do, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
  <input type="text" name="txt" onkeypress="Search" />
```

javascript

```
<script>
    function Search(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13){// enter key value is 13


     **// Your ajax request write here , and in server side you can 
**check corresponding results in database and return if data is present and take it as ajax replay****
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>
```